# Какой Кросплатформенный GUI лучший на C#?

Tags: c#, gui

Нужен для работы программы на Windows и Linux.

Смотрю на https://github.com/ddobrev/QtSharp

и

https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia

Но их не приходилось использовать.

Какие проблемы могут быть у них?

Есть что-нибудь лучше?

Comment: Кроссплатформенный UI? Тогда вам нужно Xamarin.Forms. У вас будут телефоны (iOS, Android и даже Windows Phone), Мак и Windows. UI-программы под Линукс, увы, мало востребованы, поэтому под него хороший фреймворк найти сложнее.

Comment: Avalonia в бету то непонятно вышла ли, альфа только только заканчивается. Так что если вам для продуктива - точно нет. А если для себя - минимально рабочий вариант собрать уже можно, вполне обычный xaml для разметки.

Answer (score 0):

Немного поработал с Avalonia - на текущий момент вполне рабочий инструмент для разработки, а учитывая "плюшки" типа стилей или содержимого по типу объекта в xaml - лучшего для MVVM пока не видел